# iOS programming - pList or .sqlite3 database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, plist

I'm getting into iOS programming (coming from some light Java experience) and was curious which would be a better way to setup some information I have.

I have a list of 753 "trips" (rows in a database or  in a plist) that consist of point A to point B and a preset amount of miles for that trip; so each trip would have 3 keys for a plist - or columns for a database 'pointa','pointb','miles'.

I'm curious if that dataset would be too large for a pList?

Would .sqlite3 database be better suited for something like that?

The data will be static - it will not change, and if it needs to be changed it would be very, very rarely.

I'm not sure which is ideal - it seems like matching the strings of the pointA & pointB would be easier done with a pList to get the miles (my iOS knowledge is weak enough - from what I've googled it appears quicker to learn plist than the SQL stuff).

Just looking for some feedback - which would be the 'proper' one to go with?

It looks as if long pLists have a negative impact upon app performance because it must load it into memory - but I'm curious as to how big is 'too big'.

Comment: You don't need a full-blown database for 700 triples of `double`s (or whatever). A plist, especially a binary one, does the job pretty well.

Comment: Consider coredata also.

Comment: Do you need all of the data loaded at the same time is another concern?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys - CoreData was a consideration alongside .sqlite3 - but it looks even trickier.  With my limited knowledge I am trying to keep it as simple as possible - but I will look into it some more :)

Comment: @Wain - No.  Not really - the idea is that a person will select which points they traveled between (point A) and (point B) then will click "Save", at which point there is an entry into a database that saves their name, date, pointA, pointB and miles.  I don't think that requires it all being loaded at the same time.

Comment: Plist requires you to have everything loaded. So SQLite (or, better, Core Data) will be better solutions for the future as the amount of data grows

Comment: If you haven't used SQLite or Core Data before then they are similar in complexity, just different in concept / approach. Then it depends on your background as to which will be harder (hence some people say Core Data is a "PITA"...)

Comment: From what I've gathered I will probably try my best to go the Core Data route.  It will be a struggle - but from what everyone is saying it should be the best bet.  My Dataset will not grow in terms of pointA pointB and miles - that is a set thing.  Unless we add new locations (very rare) it will never change.  But it sounds like I need to learn CoreData regardless.

Comment: If you do pursue SQLite, then use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), a nice, thin Objective-C wrapper around the cumbersome SQLite C interface. Greatly simplifies SQLite code.

Comment: Thanks for the input Rob.  I am looking into CoreData at the moment working through some tutorials to try and get my feet wet with it.  I will keep your suggestion in mind in the event CoreData proves too difficult for me at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. Use Core Data. Core Data has a ton of built in optimizations that you would end up having to implement yourself using other data stores. It also has easy iCloud integration which, although started rocky, is pretty stable now.

Comment: Core Data is hard to get right and pain in the ass to set up, and if the guy says he's a newbie into iOS programming I doubt he would be able to get Core Data right.

Comment: Just because something is a little harder doesn't mean it is not the right path to go on.

Comment: Didn't say it isn't right! It indeed would be the best solution.

Comment: I agree with @coneybeare here, Core Data is the right way to go even if it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: I'm going to look into CoreData a bit more - but at initial glance it seemed to be the most confusing of the options which is why I didn't really touch on it in my original post.  You guys bring up excellent points though - just because it's easier doesn't make it right!  Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I marked this as the answer as it seems from the discussion this is the most 'correct' method to use in terms of what should be done.

Comment: @Hanny Don't be confused by what these people say. Core Data can be an elegant solution, but it indeed is too hard for beginners, and it **is** an overkill in your case. A plist would do the job absolutely perfectly.

Comment: Thanks @H2CO3 - I appreciate your input!  I have been working through some tutorials (and tweaking them to use my own information); if it doesn't work I may go back and work with a plist - but at the end of the day I'll need to interface with a database on some level (to track trips a user is making); so I suppose diving in and learning it is the best way (or at least to try!)